How to create custom action?
I'd like to run a custom action that runs a job, but when I click on this action from the front end I see a spinner for a split second and nothing gets logged. dd($record) has no impact either.
Is it possible to run a custom action like this, or are actions only suited for basic CRUD operations and redirects?
These work fine
Action::make('View Something')
    ->url(fn($record) => 'somethings?id=' . $record->id),
EditAction::make()
    ->label('Edit')

But I'd like to do something like this
->actions([
    ActionGroup::make([
        Action::make('doSomething')
            ->action(function ($record) {
                Log::info('Do something to ' . $record->id);
                CustomJob::dispatch($record);
            }),
        ])
    ])


do you use some custom view on the table? because when i try dd($record), it still works

Filament allow use a custom action like this:
->actions([
            Action::make('customAction')
                ->action(function ($record){
                    Log::info('Id: ' . $record->id);
                }),
            EditAction::make()
        ])

This should work for you. If nothing happens, check the correctness of the namespace for the Action class.
It should be Filament\Tables\Actions\Action. Otherwise, try ensuring the logic is executed by adding requiresConfirmation()
Action::make('customAction')
    ->requiresConfirmation()
    ->action(function ($record){
        Log::info('Id: ' . $record->id);
    })

You should see a modal window prompting for confirmation of the action.
